# If a table has an unindexed column with a 1 to many relationship to an indexed column, how to optimize a query for the unindexed column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

If there is a two column table MyTable with enough records that optimization of queries is relevant.

**CorporationID** int (unindexed)

**BatchID** int (indexed)

And lets assume there is always a 1 to many relationship between CorporationID and BatchID. In other words for each BatchID there will be only one CorporationID, but for each CorporationID there will be many BatchID values.

We need to get all BatchID values where corporationID = 1.

I know the simplest solution may be to just add an index to CorporationID, but assuming that is not allowed, is there some other way to inform SQL that each BatchID corresponds to only 1 CorporationID, through a query or otherwise?

```
select distinct batchid from MyTable where corporationID = 1
```

It seems this is not effective.

```
select batchid from (select min(corporationid) corporationid, batchid 
from MyTable group by batchid) subselect where corporationid = 1
```

This is also not effective, I assume due to SQL needing to iterate needlessly through all values of corporationid? (Does an aggregate function exist to select any() value which would not have the overhead of min(), max(), sum() or avg()??)

```
select batchid 
from (
       select corporationid, batchid 
       from (
               select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batchid ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
              from mytable
            ) subselect 
       where RowNumber = 1
      ) subselect2 
where corporationid = 1
```

Would this work? By arbitrarily selecting the corporationid related to row number 1 after partitioning by batchid with no order?

Comment: Can you clarify why you wouldn't create that index. That's exactly what its designed for. Is this a purely theoretical question?

Comment: Yes it's mainly a theoretical question to try to expand my knowledge of SQL. In reality I will probably add the index to the table tomorrow even though the table is gigantic and it makes me somewhat hesitant to make changes.

Comment: There is no other way out of this. If you want to select by a column with no index then its going to have to scan.

Answer (score 1):

"assuming it is not allowed to create an index" - this is a highly unlikely assumption. Of course, you should create the index.

The most direct answer to your alternate questions that lie within your question is "no". There is no function or sub query or view or other "read" action you can make to get a list of the batches for a given CorpID. You NEED to access the corpID data to do that... all your sample queries do not work because, at some point, they NEED to access the CorpIDs to know which rows to gather for BatchIDs. Any summary or "rollup" function that might exist would still NEED to access all the pages of data to "see" them. The reading of the pages cannot be avoided.

Without changes to your architecture, it's not physically possible to optimize your query further.

However, with some changes, you could have some options (but Id guess they are much uglier than just adding the index). For instance, you could modify the structure of your BatchID to include data for both the BatchID and the CorpID. Something like "8888899999999"... the 9's are the batchID and the 8's are the CorpID. This doesn't win you much though, you're not saving any index space, but at least you dont have to index the CorpID field :) Somethings like this could be done, but I wont share any others. I dont want the really experienced people here to see this stuff and get ill. :)

You need an index on CorpID if you want to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Your explanation makes sense. Ideally I would not be storing a repeated value in the first place in every record but unfortunately I do not have access to modify the applications accessing the existing data structure, so I think adding an index will be my best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of data, I suggest putting an index on the Corporation ID column. But if you have too much data, you can define an index for each Corporation ID

Comment: I have no idea of what "define an index for each corporation ID" even means??

Comment: When You Write :
`select * from mytable where corporationid = @corporationid `.
You will see in Execution plan direct reads from index Scan (corporationid = @corporationid) which is relatively good speed

Comment: So that means you should put an index on CorporationId. I don't understand from your answer why you have two options? What does "Each CorporationID" mean as opposed to "an index on CorporationID??

Comment: When you create an index, you create a table on the main table. This table is larger when the index is based on Corporation ID.
This table is smaller if you need per Corporation ID.
When you create an index for each Corporation ID, you only look for a table containing the Corporation ID data, not more.

Comment: Still makes zero sense. Can you possibly update your answer with the actual commands that show what you mean. Still have no idea by what you mean by "an index on corporationID" vs "an index for each corporationID".

Comment: Hello . Use my answer step by step. I've put it in the new answer.
I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Part 01=>

```
/*01Create DB*/
IF DB_ID('Test01')>0
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE Test01 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE Test01
END
GO
CREATE DATABASE Test01
GO
USE Test01
Go
```

Part 02=>

```
/*02Create table*/
CREATE TABLE Table01(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Title NVARCHAR(100),
    CreationDate DATETIME,
    CorporationID INT ,
    MyID INT ,
    [GuidId1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [GuidId2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table01] ADD  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [CreationDate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table01] ADD  DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) FOR [GuidId1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table01] ADD  DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [GuidId2]
GO

CREATE TABLE Table02(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Title NVARCHAR(100),
    CreationDate DATETIME,
    CorporationID INT ,
    MyID INT ,
    [GuidId1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [GuidId2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table02] ADD  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [CreationDate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table02] ADD  DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) FOR [GuidId1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table02] ADD  DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [GuidId2]
GO
```

Part 03=>

```
/*03Add Data*/
DECLARE @I INT = 1
WHILE @I < 1000000
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Title NVARCHAR(100) = 'TITLE '+ CAST(@I AS NVARCHAR(10)), 
            @CorporationID INT = CAST((RAND()*20) + 1 AS INT), 
            @Code NVARCHAR(50) = 'CODE '+ CAST(@I AS NVARCHAR(10)) ,
            @MyID INT  = CAST((RAND()*50) + 1 AS INT)

    INSERT INTO Table01 (Title , CorporationID , Code , MyID )
    VALUES ( @Title  , @CorporationID , 'CODE '+ @Code , @MyID)

SET @I += 1
END
INSERT INTO Table02 ([Title], [CreationDate], [CorporationID], [MyID], [GuidId1], [GuidId2], [Code])
SELECT [Title], [CreationDate], [CorporationID], [MyID], [GuidId1], [GuidId2], [Code] FROM Table01
```

Part 04=>

```
/*04 CREATE INDEX*/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table01_ALL
ON Table01  (CorporationID) INCLUDE (MyID)  ;
DECLARE @QUERY  NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @J INT = 1
WHILE @J < 21 
BEGIN
    SET @QUERY += ' 

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  IX_Table02_'+CAST(@J AS NVARCHAR(5))+'
    ON Table02 (CorporationID) INCLUDE (MyID)  WHERE CorporationID = '+CAST(@J AS NVARCHAR(5))+';'
    SET @J+= 1
END
EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Part 05=>

```
/*05 READ DATA => PUSH Button CTRL + M ( EXECUTION PLAN) */
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table01] WHERE CorporationID = 10  AND MyID = 25
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table01] WITH(INDEX(IX_Table01_ALL)) WHERE CorporationID = 10  AND MyID = 25
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table02] WITH(INDEX(IX_Table02_10))  WHERE CorporationID = 10  AND MyID = 25
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

Notice IO , TIME , and EXECUTION PLAN .
Good luck

Comment: That was interesting.
Sql Server Has a feature that no one will use for millions of years.
If you were working on big data, you would see that your vision is for millions of years old befor.
Accounting operations, banking operations and so on Used this feature .I'm sorry for wasting my time answering you